# How search table data with CONCAT and where condition in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter table value in database based on user login session variable
Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM milkvalue WHERE userid = '$user_id', CONCAT(      `month`) LIKE '%".$submit."%' ";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
} else {
    $query = "select * from milkvalue where userid = '$user_id'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

function filterTable($query){
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "milk");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    return $filter_Result;          
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `userid = CONCAT('$user_id', month)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CONCAT query is incorrect. It should be

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `milkvalue` WHERE `userid` = CONCAT($userid, `month`) LIKE '%".$submit."%' "
```

Comment: Hi Nick, I am calling userid after login into page via session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION["username"];

Comment: OK, can you give me an example of what the userID concatenated string needs to match to?

Comment: I am using random number to generate userID and same ID is my LOGIN ID for users, Now admin insert some value in Database table based on userID.

Comment: Here My $user_id = $_SESSION["username"]; where assinging session variable in $user_id and table value should display based on userID

Comment: can you share me your mail sho that i can tell you what i am looking for

Comment: Can you just tell me what you are trying to do? Are you trying to display users who logged in for a certain month? Why are you wanting to concatenate the strings? Also, what does `$_POST['submit']` contain?